# Google App Engine Jinja2 and Markupsafe

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

Google says that MarkupSafe makes jina2 run faster [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

I've added it to my Yaml file like this.

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
```

Jina2 says it checks to see if markupsafe is installed [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/faq/?highlight=markupsafe)

My question is, how do I really know it is working?  I inserted a bunch of html via my jinja form and it didn't get escaped.  In short, I've read the docs and can't find a clear answer to what markupsafe does, and why I need it.  The only snippet of information I have that jinja2 looks for it and makes jinja faster.  I have no idea if its really working.

Comment: I believe this is not App Engine question at this point. Check with Jinja2 guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK markupsafe doesn't affect the jinja2 semantics, only its performance. So the only way to find out if it worked is to time it. Or you could stop worrying. :-) That app.yaml syntax looks fine.

If you want jinja2 to escape your variables, you must turn on autoescape when creating the Environment, like this:

```
env = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
  autoescape=True)
```

Comment: Wow,Guido!  I am completely star struck.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.